# AAD: Is it possible to put Microsoft Graph open extension into optionalClaims in AD Application Manifest?

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What I want to do: Invite new user to Active Directory and at the same time assign him extension of organisationId. This extension property will then be returned in claims when user is logged into same application.

AD Graph API support adding directory extensions which we can easily add into AD Application Manifest as optionalClaims like this:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
      {
        "name": "extension_94dd5b3a05a1416f8481eb6713b6ba08_organisationId",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      },
      {
        "name": "extension_organisationId",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      }
    ],
    "accessToken": [
      {
        "name": "extension_94dd5b3a05a1416f8481eb6713b6ba08_organisationId",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      },
      {
        "name": "extension_organisationId",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      }
    ],
    "saml2Token": []
  },
```

Great. AD Graph API doesn't support new operation of inviting user that Microsoft Graph API supports.

So I build whole custom app to allow inviting users to Active directory, and you can use open extensions to add to user object. All great. Problem now is how do I add that open extensions that are on user object into optionalClaims in application manifest?

As you can see from optionalClaims above I tried "extension_organisationId" but no luck in returning it in claims. First one "extension_94dd5b3a05a1416f8481eb6713b6ba08_organisationId" is directory extension done with old AD Graph API, and I get it in claims.

Is it me or is microsoft doing things so sloppy?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing from Azure AD Graph API are [Schema Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension), not [Open Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension).  Microsoft Graph supports both and they each have different behaviors.

Schema Extensions are strongly typed and stored with the resource itself:

> Schema extensions allow you to define a schema to extend and add strongly-typed custom data to a resource type. The custom data appears as a complex type on the extended resource.

Open Extensions are untyped and stored *along side* the resource:

> Open extensions (formerly known as Office 365 data extensions) give you an easy way to directly add untyped properties to a resource in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Can you then use those in application manifest to return as claims? In url you gave I don't see how you add new value to schema extension to user?

Comment: Microsoft Graph's Schema Extensions and Azure AD Graph API's Directory Schema Extensions are the same resources (unlike Open Extensions which only exist in Graph). The Graph documentation includes a walkthrough of created and setting schema extensions for a `group` resource. The same steps would be used for a `user`: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups

Comment: Authorization_RequestDenied when I try to add schema extension, and I am admin pretty much and only user of my AD. I tried to give all permission still doesn't work.

Comment: Creating them requires `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permissions. Also, make sure you're using either the Auth Code or Implicit Grant (this isn't supported using the Client Credentials grant).

Comment: [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-directory-extension-optional-claims) states that:
    "Schema and open extensions are not supported by optional claims, only the AAD-Graph style directory extensions."
I don't think you can do what you are asking within optionalClaims in the manifest.